# jQuery update object by its elements event

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm kinda newbie in JS objects, but I'd like to learn correct ways of doing things.

I'm writing a Class and it is mostly based on element that is passed to constructor. I want this element to have an event that updates the object.
I made it so it happens, but this just feels "*hacky*".

```
function SomeClass(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.mouseX = 0;
    this.mouseY = 0;
    this.setMousePosition = function(posX, posY) {
        this.mouseX = posX;
        this.mouseY = posY;
    };
    this.listenMousePosition = function() {
        var obj = this;
        $(this.element).on('mousemove',null, {obj: obj}, function(e, obj)  {
            e.data.obj.setMousePosition(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
            $('#output').html('X: ' + e.data.obj.mouseX + '; Y: ' + e.data.obj.mouseY);
        })
    }
    this.listenMousePosition();

    return this;
}

window.contentDiv = new SomeClass($(".content")[0]);
```

Is there a better way of doing this or is this the way to roll?

As I checked - I can't just pass it to function as you see in link: https://jsfiddle.net/nooorz24/v6f1jydm/7/

Comment: Well one you don't need `e.data.obj` you are able to just use `obj` since it's in the upperscope

Comment: @PatrickEvans I added a fiddle. As you see `obj` is undefined inside the function

Comment: Because you defined `obj` as a function parameter when that isn't passed to the callback, `function(e, obj)` so it overrides the outer `obj`. Just remove that parameter

Comment: Please..... stop doing `$(".content")[0]`.  You are looking up the element, and then breaking it out of the jQuery object.  And then later you stick it in `$(this.element)` to create another jQuery object.  Take off the `[0]` and remove the unnecessary breaking out of and construction of a new jQuery object.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks for pointing that out :) Would that be like best practise?

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for pointing that out :) a rookie mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least a couple ways you could do this.  The issue here is that when you get inside the function `this` changes from referencing the class instance to the method.

## Reference another variable

By using an external variable, we don't care if `this` changes.

```
var self = this;

this.listenMousePosition = function() {
    $(self.element).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        self.setMousePosition(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
        $('#output').html('X: ' + self.mouseX + '; Y: ' + self.mouseY);
    });
};
```

## Use an arrow function

Arrow functions do not change what `this` references.

```
this.listenMousePosition = () => {
    $(this.element).on('mousemove', e => {
        this.setMousePosition(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
        $('#output').html('X: ' + this.mouseX + '; Y: ' + this.mouseY);
    });
};
```

Take note though that arrow functions do not work in IE versions prior to Edge.